# Instrument-Identification tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The first question I asked on this site was about identfiying instruments in a music track 
 (What happened to that question ? I dont see it in my past questions list !)
It got deleted because "Identifiying instruments wont help anyone"
So what is reason of adding "identifiy_instruments" badge ?
I need to know instruments used in a music track but I dont want it to get deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that one was closed and then auto-deleted as off topic.

We do not have an identify_instruments tag.

The [identification](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) tag (which you used on your post) is not used to identify which instruments are used in a piece of music, but as you will see from some of the other examples using that tag, for identifying from pictures and documentation what a specific instrument is.

There is also a bit of use in identifying chords and I think one example of trying to identify a piece of music by Mozart.

Comment: To be fair, the tag info for `identification` states "Find the name, term or phrase for the presented technique, instrument or notation", without suggesting that there are restrictions on how those should be 'presented'.

Comment: @topomorto that's true, I think we'll need to update the tag wording.

Comment: @DrMayhem Out of curiosity: It seems identification of instruments was on-topic when the tag description was written, but is off-topic now. Can you maybe add a link to the meta.post(s) that discuss this changes? I found this Question with answers that didn't exclude instrument-IDs per se: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/why-are-instrument-identification-questions-off-topic

Comment: identification of instruments is not off topic, Marzipan. Please look at my post above.

Comment: I've quoted you [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3415/37941).